# Delphi Menu Merging problem

Tags: delphi, vcl, menu

I'm trying to merge two main menus together, but am having problems getting the right result with sub-items. I'm using the GroupIndex property on my MenuItems to control the merging/insertion.

Menu1 (with groupindices) is like this

- File=10

  - Open=11
  - Close=12
- Edit=20

  - Cut=21
  - Paste=22
- Help=90

  - About=91

Menu2 is like this

- Edit=20

  - Clear=23
- Widgets=30

  - Widget1=31
  - Widget2=32

And I'm doing

```
  Menu1.Merge(Menu2);
```

I want the combined menu to have a new top menu "Widgets"and a new "Clear" command in the Edit menu. "Widgets" is working fine, but the Edit Menu has lost cut and paste, which wasn't what I wanted.

How can I stop the Cut and Paste commands from disappearing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The menu merge feature in Delphi works a bit differently than what you'd expect: it's non-recursive (unfortunately!). That means that when you call `Menu1.Merge`, Menu1's "Edit" menu gets *replaced* by Menu2's.

You have two options:

- Add "Cut" and "Paste" manually to Menu2.
- Write your own Merge function.

I had the same problem a while ago (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152405/how-do-i-merge-tmainmenus-that-use-separate-imagelists-and-retain-the-correct-i#153799)):

> What I eventually ended up with, is
>   using the
>   [Toolbar2000](http://jrsoftware.org/tb2k.php)
>   package for all my menus and toolbars.
>   You can then download a very nice
>   piece of code, called
>   [TB2Merge](http://flocke.vssd.de/prog/code/pascal/tb2merge/),
>   which does exactly what you want.

You could also base any custom-written menu merge code on TB2Merge, I guess...

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that might be the answer. I'll have a look at Toolbar2000